# Ternary Expression with Interfaces as a Base Class

Tags: c#-4.0, if-statement, ternary-operator

I am attempting to create a ternary expression and I am getting the following error

"Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between LiveSubscription and DisconnectedSubscription"

The same logic works in an if statement, but I wanted to understand why it won't work in a ternary expression -

Here is the gist of what I am trying to do:

```
public interface IClientSubscription
{
    bool TryDisconnect();
}

public class LiveSubscription : IClientSubscription
{
    public bool TryDisconnect()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class DisconnectedSubscription : IClientSubscription
{
    public bool TryDisconnect()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class ConnectionManager
{
    public readonly IClientSubscription Subscription;

    public ConnectionManager(bool IsLive)
    {
        // This throws the exception
        Subscription = (IsLive)
            ? new LiveSubscription()
            : new DisconnectedSubscription();

        // This works
        if (IsLive)
        {
            Subscription = new LiveSubscription();
        }
        else
        {
            Subscription = new DisconnectedSubscription();
        }
    }
}
```

I could always switch it to an if/else but I wanted to understand what is going wrong first!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to cast at least one of the operands to `IClientSubscription`:

```
Subscription = (IsLive)
            ? (IClientSubscription)new LiveSubscription()
            : new DisconnectedSubscription();
```

The reason is that the ternary expression is of a certain type which is determined by the operands. Basically, it tries to cast the second operand to the type of the first or vice versa. Both fail here, because `LiveSubscription` isn't an `DisconnectedSubscription` and vice versa.
The compiler doesn't check whether both share a common base type.

---

Trying to answer your question in the comment:

No, ternary expressions are not some sort of object, but a ternary expression is the right hand part of an assignment. Each right hand part expression of an assignment has a certain type, otherwise it would be impossible to assign this expression to the variable on the left hand side.
Examples:

- `var x = Guid.NewGuid()`

  The right hand side expression (`Guid.NewGuid()`) is of type `Guid`, because the method `NewGuid()` returns a `Guid`.
- `var x = y.SomeMethod()`

  The right hand side expression is of the type of the return type of `SomeMethod()`.
- `var x = IsLive ? "a" : 1`

  This is obviously invalid, isn't it? What type should `x` be? A `string` or an `int`?
  This would lead to the exact same error message that you had with your code.
- Your example a bit changed:

  ```
  var subscription = (IsLive) ? new LiveSubscription()
                              : new DisconnectedSubscription();
  ```

  Note the `var` before `subscription`, we now initialize a new variable, not an existing. I think even here, it is obvious what the problem is: What type should `subscription` be? `LiveSubscription` or `DisconnectedSubscription`? It can be neither, because depending on `IsLive` it needs to be either the one or the other.

About the comparison with `if`:

In your code where you assign a new `LiveSubscription` instance or a new `DisconnectedSubscription` instance to `Subscription` an implicit cast to `IClientSubscription` is occurring, because the compiler knows that `Subscription` is of type `IClientSubscription` and both `LiveSubscription` and `DisconnectedSubscription` can implicitly be converted to that interface.
The assignment with the ternary expression is a bit different, because the compiler first tries to evaluate the ternary expression and only afterwards it tries to assign it to `Subscription`. This means that the compiler doesn't know that the result of the ternary expression needs to be of type `IClientSubscription`.

Comment: What do you mean by the 'Ternary expression is of a certain type'?  What implications does that have for using a ternary expression vs. an equivalent if/else statement?  I was under the impression that a ternary expression was simple syntactic sugar - but is it sometime more?

Comment: @William: Please read the complete answer, especially the paragraph after the sentence you quoted. I am of the opinion that it is quite clear.

Comment: I read the complete answer but I'm not sure what implications that has on using ternaries vs. if statements. i.e. WHY are ternary expressions of a certain type? Are they some sort of object?

Comment: @William: Please see update. I hope this makes it a bit clearer. I guess, Eric or Jon could explain it more clearly with fewer words.