# Why conditional statement needs cast?

Tags: c#, oop, interface, casting, conditional-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ternary Expression with Interfaces as a Base Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810471/ternary-expression-with-interfaces-as-a-base-class)

Classes:

```
interface ISms {
  void f_SendSms();
}

class SmsVodafone : ISms {
  public void f_SendSms(){
        // ...
  }
}

class SmsClickatell : ISms {
  public void f_SendSms(){
        // ...
  }
}
```

This works:

```
ISms sms = null;
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_bilgi.M_Originator))
{
    sms = new SmsVodafone();
}
else
{
    sms = new SmsClickatell();
}
```

This works too:

```
ISms sms = null;
sms = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_bilgi.M_Originator)
        ? (ISms) new SmsVodafone()
        : new SmsClickatell();
```

This doesn't work:

```
ISms sms = null;
sms = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_bilgi.M_Originator)
          ? new SmsVodafone()
          : new SmsClickatell();
```

Why?

Comment: I assume it is C# - change the tag if I am wrong

Comment: I think in the last code sample you meant to drop the `(ISms)`

Comment: I see no difference between your second and third example?!

Comment: Must be a typo but I don't see a difference between 2nd and 3rd code example

Comment: Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9810587/572644) in the question linked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a ternary expression `a ? b : c`, both expressions `b` and `c` must be convertible to the same type, which must be one of `b`'s type or `c`'s type.

`SmsVodafone` is not convertible to `SmsClickatell`, and `SmsClickatell` is not convertible to `SmsVodafone`. That's why you get an error.