# Why won't the shorthand version of my 'if' compile with different implementations?

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, types, interface

I have the following interface:

```
interface IMyInterface {}
```

And the following two implementations:

```
class MyImplementation : IMyInterface {}

class MyOtherImplementation : IMyInterface {}
```

Given that, the following compiles:

```
IMyInterface ReturnImplementation()
{
   if(condition)
   {
      return new MyImplementation();
   }
   else
   {
      return new MyOtherImplementation();
   }
}
```

But *this* does not:

```
IMyInterface ReturnImplementation()
{
   return condition ? new MyImplementation() : new MyOtherImplementation();
}
```

### Question

Why? What am I misunderstanding in assuming that it should compile? Is it as simple as the fact that the shorthand `if` specifies the exact same type is chosen from? If so, why? Why is it restricted in this way?

Comment: What error does the compiler give you?

Comment: That an implicit conversion can't be made. But I'm not asking it to convert anything, I'm asking it to return an `IMyInterface`, which I'm doing.

Comment: I'm not convinced that's a duplicate. Both of my types implement a specified interface.

Comment: It's sort of a duplicate, but just about different enough to make it worth not closing, IMO.

Comment: @Jon without editing the question I can't see what was the previous duplicate target, but I think [Ternary Expression with Interfaces as a Base Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810471/ternary-expression-with-interfaces-as-a-base-class) explains it pretty well, key being _"The compiler doesn't check whether both share a common base type"_.

Comment: As an aside - do people think the compiler *should* check? Would it be a nice addition? Or is it like this for a reason? Thanks for all responses so far.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Yes, that's a better one than the previous one (which was between a `DateTime?` and `DBNull.Value`, hoping to get `object`). I'm happy for this to be closed, but would like it to stick around, as this is the kind of topic which can be hard to find the right question for if you don't already know the answer :)

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ: No, I'm very happy with the behaviour as it stands. Anything else would almost certainly be *way* more complicated. It's already a pity that the conditional operator doesn't perform inference in *quite* the same way as `new[] { expr1, expr2 }`, although pinning down exactly where they differ is tricky. (Funnily enough, I was trying to come up with an example of that just earlier today...)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What am I misunderstanding in assuming that it should compile?

You're not reading the spec :)

Basically, conditional operator requires that *either* the second and third operands are of the same type, or that there's an implicit conversion from one of them to the other (and not the other way round). In other words, the overall result type of the operator has to be either the type of the second operand or the type of the third operand.

That's the reason the compiler is giving you an error message about implicit conversions - you *are* asking it to try to implicitly convert either `MyImplementation` to `MyOtherImplementation` or vice versa.

In your case, you want the result type to be `IMyInterface` - so you should cast one of the operands - either of them - to that type:

```
return condition ? (IMyInterface) new MyImplementation() : new MyOtherImplementation();
```

At that point the compiler will note that there's an implicit conversion from `MyOtherImplementation` to `IMyInterface` but not vice versa, and pick `IMyInterface` as the overall type of the operator.

Comment: Nice! didn't think about casting in this way to be explicit about the type it should expect. I like that.